# I failed at creating a simple language function, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php

I tried to create a simple language function, but I can't get it to work. The idea should be clear. I'm not getting any error messages but it won't show my text either. This is my code:

inc/text.php:

```
<?php

$show = array(

"welcome" => "Welkom @ ....", 
'test' => true 

);

function show($foo) {

echo $show[$foo];

}

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php show("welcome"); ?>
```

Comment: it can not recognize $show in function

Comment: You're not getting any error, because you missed to enable error reporting: put this at the first line of your script: `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and PHP will tell you about the one or other problem your script has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're declaring `$show` outside of the scope of `function show($foo)`

either declare $show inside the function or do this:

```
$show = array(); //blah blah

function show($foo)
{
    global $show;
    echo $show[$foo];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make $show array global scope within the function, and return the value not echo it

```
<?php

$show = array(
"welcome" => "Welkom @ ....", 
'test' => true 
);

function show($foo) {
global $show;
return $show[$foo];
}
?>

<p><?php echo show("welcome"); ?></p>
```

Comment: Instead of suggesting using globals, you should have seen that you can solve this with a simple array access instead of calling a function. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Using return and echo simultaneously seems a little weird to me. Is it wrong to use echo inside of the function declaration?

Comment: IMO functions shouldn't echo, as if you call that function when building the page, it will echo at the top, i always build my page first as echo'ing requires more resources then declaring a variable, all my projects have only 1 echo and its normally on the last line, i hate code that echos on each line or breaks in and out of php

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `SHOW` array, so it is accesible from the function.

You have sevral methods to do this

- Global variable
- Pass it like a parameter
- Declare the array in a function

Example of declaration inside a function

```
function show($foo) {
  $show = array(
    "welcome" => "Welkom @ ....", 
    'test' => true 
  );

  echo $show[$foo];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a function for that:

```
<?php echo $show["welcome"]; ?>
```

That should already do it. Let me know if that is not helpful and why.

Comment: That's not really an option because i'm going to implement multiple languages in my function.

Comment: Oh really? And how does the answer you accepted differ conceptually then? It's exactly the same, you only encapsulate it inside a function.